# Ruby "while" what am i doing wrong here

Tags: ruby, while-loop

right now im trying to ask the user if he wants to hit or stay during a blackjack game.

if he hits it deals a card to him, calculates total, and gives him the total. I have all of that down correctly. BUT i don't know how i can re-ask him if he wants to hit again if his total is 20 or less.

```
while p1total <= 20 && hit_stay == '1'
puts "would you like to 1.) hit or 2.) stay"
    hit_stay = gets.chomp
    playercards << deck.pop
    p1total = calculate_total(playercards)
    puts "You got delt a #{playercards[2]} You now have #{p1total}"
break
```

any idea how i can REASK the question "Would you like to hit or stay" again after he's already made the choice to hit?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with your code?

Comment: The `break` where you have it located will exit the loop after the first iteration, regardless of the loop conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Close the while loop with an 'end' and not break. Also make sure you're declaring those variables outside of the while loop. And you have to check for the response again inside the while or you will still give a card one last time even if the player says stay.

```
p1total = 0
hit_stay = '1'

while p1total <= 20 && hit_stay == '1'
    puts "would you like to 1.) hit or 2.) stay"
    hit_stay = gets.chomp
    break if hit_stay != '1'
    playercards << deck.pop
    p1total = calculate_total(playercards)
    puts "You got delt a #{playercards.last} You now have #{p1total}"
end
```

Ideally, I think you should write a separate method to do this and just call the method again when the player asks for a hit, but I can't write it that way here.

Comment: Edited the last line to say puts "You got delt a #{playercards.last}" to return the last card.